# (django-testing) assertIs error

Tags: python, django, automated-tests, assertions, django-testing

I have tried a simple test and got this error message in the console:

```
 AIL: test_get (navbar.test.ContextManagerTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/me/049C11249C1111B2/backup me/Freizeit/Django Projekte/mysitetest/lib/navbar/test.py", line 16, in test_get
    self.assertIs(cm.get('hi/du',0), 'hi')
AssertionError: 'hi' is not 'hi'
```

We can see in the last line, `cm.get('hi/du',0)` returned `'hi'`. But why the test has failed than?

---

First, I thaught there could be an error, but neither that code line:

```
self.assertIs('hi','hi')
```

nor this one:

```
self.assertIs(['hi'][0],'hi')
```

nor this one:

```
self.assertIs(cm.get('hi',0),'hi')
```

failed.

---

For better understanding, I add the code of `cm.get(mypattern,number)`:

```
def get(self, mypattern, number):
  parts = mypattern.split('/').strip()
  return parts[number]
```

---

This is the code of the test that failed:

```
def test_get(self):
        cm = context.ContextManager([])

        self.assertIs(cm.get('hi',0), 'hi')
        self.assertIs(cm.get('hi/du',0), 'hi') #this line failed
        self.assertIs(cm.get('hi/du',1), 'du')
```

It looks like there was some trouble with the `split()` function, but, at least, `cm.get('hi/du',0)` returned `'hi'`, as we can the in the stacktrace above.

For remembering I add the relevant lines:

```
self.assertIs(cm.get('hi/du',0), 'hi')
    AssertionError: 'hi' is not 'hi'
```

---

Small detail (I don't know whether this is important): I started the test with `python3 manage.py test lib/navbar`.

---

So you know why that failed? Or do you have at least some guesses?
Thank your for reading this!

Comment: can you give some more info on what is `context.ContextManager`.
And why do you need to use assertIs? , basically it asserts whether the objects are same or not. I think you can use AsserEqual if you just want to compare values.

Comment: Tank you! That was the information I needed. Write it as an answer and I'll mark it as solved. That was the misstake. Sometimes it's at least easier than it seemes ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The assertion method you need is `assertEqual` not `assertIs`.

`assertEqual(a, b)`: Compares the values of a and b

`assertIs(a, b)`: Checks whether a and b point to the same object, i.e. id of both a and b is the same